# With jquery want to ad to html id &#x2191; or img src

Tags: jquery, html

Here are examples http://jsfiddle.net/j5a1ffLL/15/

For example only html all ok

```
<div>
<a href="#">Only html &#8593; &#x2191;</a>
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBwAKAIABAI3JlgAAACH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAHAAoAAAIPjGEZqNt+gJxrsnrP26oAADs=" >
</div>
```

Want with jquery to show `&#8593; &#x2191;` or `data:image/gif;base64,...`

like

```
<a href="#" id="third">With jquery third</a>
<span id="span_third"></span>

$('#third').text( $('#third').text() + ' &#8593; &#x2191;' );
$('#span_third').text( ' &#8593; &#x2191;' );
```

But instead of arrows (With jquery third ↑ ↑ ) see

```
With jquery third &#8593; &#x2191; &#8593; &#x2191;
```

How to show the arrows with jquery? Or may be with jquery need to change class and set arrows in the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `html()` method instead of `text()`:

```
$('#second').html( $('#second').text() + '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBwAKAIABAI3JlgAAACH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAHAAoAAAIPjGEZqNt+gJxrsnrP26oAADs=" >' );
$('#first').html( $('#first').text() + ' some more text' );
$('#third').html( $('#third').text() + ' &#8593; &#x2191;' );
$('#span_third').html( ' &#8593; &#x2191;' );
```

When you use the `text()` method expect to get/set the encoded text (exactly how you want to see it rendered).

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j5a1ffLL/18/)